# How can I build a condition based query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I can do this in Code Igniter:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->from->('node');
if ($published == true)
{
    $this->db->where('published', 'true');
}
if (isset($year))
{
    $this->db->where('year >', $year);
}
$this->db->get();
```

How can this code be translated so that it works in Laravel?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Fluent you can do:

```
$query = DB::table('node');

if ($published == true)
    $query->where('published', '=', 1);

if (isset($year))
    $query->where('year', '>', $year);

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: This only returns an array. is there a way for this to return a collection?

Comment: this works on paginated date too, just swap get for paginate or simplePaginate

Comment: We can write like this (More precise way):

$query = DB::table('node')->when($published, function ($q, $published) {
        return $q->where('published', 1);
    })->when($year, function($q, $year) {
        return $q->where('year', '>', $year);
    })->get()

Comment: now this is not the proper way. you can use when() method. 
check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: I wouldn't say this isn't the 'proper' way @syam lal.  There is a different way based on the docs above, but I personally find this easier to read, so would actually consider *this* to be the proper way.  But, to each his own...

Answer (score 25):

As of [Laravel 5.2.27](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12878), you can avoid breaking the chain by writing your conditions as so:

PHP < 7.4

```
$query = DB::table('node')
    ->when($published, function ($q) use ($published) {
        return $q->where('published', 1);
    })
    ->when($year, function($q) use ($year) {
        return $q->where('year', '>', $year);
    })
    ->get();
```

PHP >= 7.4 (more concise)

```
$query = DB::table('node')
    ->when($published, fn ($q) => $q->where('published', 1))
    ->when($year, fn ($q) => $q->where('year', '>', $year))
    ->get();
```

To use Eloquent, just swap `$query = DB::table('node')` with `Node::` but realize if both conditions fail, you'll get everything in the table back unless you check for some other condition before querying the db/model or from within the query itself.

Comment: I don't really see the advantages of `when`. To me a simple if statement looks way cleaner, easier to read and probably faster to execute.

Comment: @ArnovanOordt What notication looks cleaner is subjective, as I find the `when` notation more clean because it gives one context of the intention making it easier to read for me. That being said, I would like to see some data backing up your intuition that it is faster to execute. If I had to guess the differences are not significant or maybe not even measurable.

Answer (score 13):

Here is how you can accomplish your query:

```
$year = 2012;
$published = true;

DB::table('node')
->where(function($query) use ($published, $year)
{
    if ($published) {
        $query->where('published', 'true');
    }

    if (!empty($year) && is_numeric($year)) {
        $query->where('year', '>', $year);
    }
})
->get( array('column1','column2') );
```

To find more information, I recommend reading through Fluent and Eloquent in the Laravel docs.
http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent

Answer (score 11):

I have not seen it here. You can even start your query like

`$modelQuery = Model::query();`

and then chain other query command afterwards. Maybe it will be helpful for someone new.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Model::when()` in Condition or you can create `Builder::micro()`

For Example

```
$results = Model::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->when($request->customer_id, function($query) use ($request){
        return $query->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

If You need to create micro for a condition then. follow below instruction.

**Write thic code in your serverice provider**

```
Builder::macro('if', function ($condition, $column, $operator, $value) {
    if ($condition) {
        return $this->where($column, $operator, $value);
    }

    return $this;
});
```

**Use Like Below Example**

```
$results = Model::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->if($request->customer_id, 'customer_id', '=', $request->customer_id)
    ->get();
```

Ref: [themsaid](http://themsaid.com/laravel-query-conditions-20160425/)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use Eloquent you can use it like, I'm not sure that whereNotNull is the best use but I couldn't find another method to return what we really want to be an empty query instance:

```
$query = Model::whereNotNull('someColumn');
if(x < y)   
    {
        $query->where('column1', 'LIKE', '%'. $a .'%');
    }else{
        $query->where('column2', 'LIKE', '%'. $b .'%');
    }
$results = $query->get();
```

This way any relationships still work, for example in your view you can still use

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result->someRelationship()->someValue;
}
```

There is a good amount of info on here http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-queries about this sort of stuff.

Comment: whereRaw(1) might be a better alternative to whereNotNull(fieldname)

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel > 5.2 you can use `when()`:

```
$results = DB::table('orders')
    ->where('branch_id', Auth::user()->branch_id)
    ->when($request->customer_id, function($query) use ($request){
        return $query->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Container/Container.html#method_when

Blog post: https://themsaid.com/laravel-query-conditions-20160425/

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Models\User;

$query = User::query();

if ($request->has('name')) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%');
}

if ($request->has('age')) {
    $query->where('age', '>=', $request->input('age'));
}

// Execute query
$users = $query->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This way is better then using ->when because ->when only accepts boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Building a condition-based query using the query builder:**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('active', true)
            ->orWhere('age', '>', 18)
            ->get();
```

**If you're using Eloquent ORM, you can achieve the same result using the Eloquent query builder:**

```
$users = User::where('active', true)
             ->orWhere('age', '>', 18)
             ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

for eloquent query i used following that executes only if where condition has value

```
->where(function($query) use ($value_id)
                    {

                            if ( ! is_null($value_id)) 
                                $query->where('vehicle_details.transport_type_id', $value_id);

                    })
```

Answer (score -1):

We can write like this (More precise way):

```
$query = DB::table('node')->when($published, function ($q, $published) {
        return $q->where('published', 1);
    })->when($year, function($q, $year) {
        return $q->where('year', '>', $year);
    })->get()
```

Not mentioned in Laravel docs. Here is pull [request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18419).