# How can I build a condition based query in Laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering how can I build a condition based query in Laravel using eloquent?

I've found how to do it with a [raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179817/1783311) but that that's not what I want also the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522556/1783311) isn't that dynamic at least not as dynamic as I want it to be.

What I try to achieve is to create a dynamic WHERE query based on certain conditions, for example if the field is filled or not.

If I use the following code,

```
        $matchThese = [
            'role' => 'user',
            'place' => \Input::get('location')
        ];

        $availableUsers = User::where($matchThese)->take($count)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
```

The query will fail if I don't send a location as POST value. I don't want it to fail I want it to skip to the next WHERE clause in the query. So basically if there's no place given don't search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up the query and include the `->where()` clause depending on whether or not you have the location in your input:

```
$query = User::where('role', 'user');

$query = \Input::has('location') ? $query->where('location', \Input::get('location')) : $query;

$availableUsers = $query->take($count)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just build the array with an if condition:

```
$matchThese = [
    'role' => 'user',
];
if(\Input::has('location')){
    $matchThese['place'] = \Input::get('location');
}
$availableUsers = User::where($matchThese)->take($count)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
```

Comment: thanks! It worked I also got the same answer from the Laravel slack, the only difference was that the user provided a shorthand if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $query = DB::table('table_name');

   if($something == "something"){
      $query->where('something', 'something');
   }

   $some_variable= $query->where('published', 1)->get();
```

You can use something like this.