# Laravel if condition query

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, if-statement

I have four input fields :
Like this

```
$cou = Input::get('activitycou');
$type = Input::get('activitytype');
$Des = Input::get('activityDes');
```

I do the following :

```
If ($type!=null){
$query=Activity::where('id', $type)->get();   
}
If ($Des!=null){
$query=Activity::where('des_id', $Des)->get();   
}
```

etc
However the problem is that $query is not displayed correctly can someone suggest a solution.

Comment: I need the query for my post view.So it needs to be query at every if.

Comment: Is it throwing any error?

Comment: no but the query is connected and gives me combined results what I want is each query a result maybe another way than if

Comment: how should i approach this?

Comment: I mean when i choose the first one there is no output.

Comment: When I choose two out of three the results are combined

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179758/how-can-i-build-a-condition-based-query-in-laravel

Comment: I have tried this tutorial it doesn't work for me because I need the query after every if.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the result combined with all of your options you can do the follow (with `union` method you can combine multiple queries):

```
If ($type!=null && $Des!=null && $cou!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $type);   
   $query2 = Activity::where('des_id', $Des);
   $query3 = Activity::where('des_id', $cou);
   $allQueries = $query1->union($query2)->union($query3)->get();
 } elseif ($type!=null && $Des!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $type);   
   $query2 = Activity::where('des_id', $Des);
   $allQueries = $query1->union($query2)->get();
 } elseif ($type!=null && $cou!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $type);   
   $query2 = Activity::where('des_id', $cou);
   $allQueries = $query1->union($query2)->get();
 } elseif ($type!=null && $cou!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $type);   
   $query2 = Activity::where('des_id', $Des);
   $allQueries = $query1->union($query2)->get();
 } elseif ($Des!=null && $cou!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $cou);   
   $query2 = Activity::where('des_id', $Des);
   $allQueries = $query1->union($query2)->get();
 } elseif ($type!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $type)->get();
 } elseif ($Des!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $Des)->get();
 } elseif ($cou!=null){
   $query1 = Activity::where('id', $cou)->get();
 }
```

Comment: I will use it but I want for everyone of the three of them .Its a user he picks destination if the destination is not null i want the Query to be bulit.If he picks the type only i want the Query to be built.

Comment: you can do it with if else like my answer

Comment: i will try it but i did something similar and did not work it  kept asking me to use the first condition (Choose destination) no matter what.

Comment: is there a way to make this without ifs?

Comment: I don't know any better way without if else

Comment: have you tried allqueries at this example will it output correctly?