# Laravel 5 mysql query ->when condition

Tags: php, laravel-5

My query looks like this at the moment, it should work.

```
$status = 'active';

$data = DB::table('applicant')
->when($status, function($query) use ($status){
            return $query->where('Status', $status);})
->get();
```

But i am getting this error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::when()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code: the Closure is not closed, try to write line 5 as follow:

```
return $query->where('Status', $status);})
```

Comment: sorry i did have those, when i copied and pasted it did not copy. Still throws the same error, might be a version issue as it works on laravel 5.2.39 , the above version is 5.0.16 .

Comment: I think also is a version issue: the when() function was added in 5.2.34

Comment: do you know of an alternative way to do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179758/how-can-i-build-a-condition-based-query-in-laravel